JUnit test in intellIj doesn't run
I have a problem in the JUnit test files in IntelliJ IDEA, the problem appears since the **module-info.java **was added.
I have this error when I run the JUnit test class:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.engine.UniqueId (in unnamed module @0x7e0b37bc) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x7e0b37bc
    at org.junit.platform.engine.UniqueId.forEngine(UniqueId.java:69)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.<clinit>(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:72)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)

The following **requires **were added in the module-info.java file:
module java_module {
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires jsch;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.params;
    requires java.desktop;

    requires org.junit.platform.commons;
    exports main to javafx.graphics;

    opens ui to javafx.fxml;
}



If I delete the module-info.java, the JUnit test run without any problems.
So what I have to add in the module-info.java and how can I solve this problem??
Note: I have the latest JUnit version, and I tried the reinstall IntelliJ to avoid any conflict but I still have this error.
I tried to run the JUnit test in IntelliJ.
I tried to reinstall IntelliJ but that did not solve the problem.

for us to help, you would need to share the exception in the question as a text and not an image.

Ok, I edited it, the exception is written as a text.

Can you share the test code also? Is it a Maven/Gradle project? Would it be possible for you to kindly provide a minimal sample project for me to reproduce the issue while ensuring that your sensitive code is not included in GitHub or Google Drive? Thank you!

Below is the an example of the JUnit test:
class SpelerTest {  private Speler speler;  private static final int HUIDIG_JAAR = 2024;  @ParameterizedTest  @ValueSource(strings= {"abcdef", "abcdef123"})  void Gebruikersnaam_GeldigeWaarden_maaktSpeler(String gebruikersnaam) {    Speler speler=new Speler(gebruikersnaam, 2000);    assertEquals(gebruikersnaam, speler.getGebruikersnaam());    assertEquals(0,speler.getAantalGespeeld());   assertEquals(0,speler.getAantalGewonnen());  } }

Can you share the full project as I can't reproduce it with a simple javafx Gradle project? Does the module-info.java sit only in the src/main/java folder?
